# Custom Metrics not shown in App Insights with Telemetry Client

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, telemetry, appinsights

My application is an ASP.NET Core 6 application. I am using Telemetry client of Application Insights and calling `GetMetric` to log custom metrics in the Azure Portal.

I am using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version 2.21.0

The Telemetry Client is injected using a constructor:

```
public RaftService (ILogger<RaftService> logger,
                    IHttpClientFactory clientFactory,
                    IOptions<RaftOptions> raftOptions,
                    IOrderNoteService orderNoteService,
                    TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    _options = raftOptions;
    _orderNoteService = orderNoteService;
    _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
}
```

I call the `GetMetric` and `TrackValue` methods as follows:

```
var _paymentAPIStatusCodeMetric = _telemetryClient.GetMetric("PaymentAPIStatusCode");
_paymentAPIStatusCodeMetric.TrackValue(Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode));
```

I am specifying the connection string in my `appsettings.json` file like this:

[image]

When I run the application locally in VS 2022, I can see the metrics getting logged. My `TelemetryClient` object looks as follows. I see the instrumentation key is assigned and the connection string is populated.:

[image]

When I deploy my application as an App Service, custom metrics do not get logged. My `TelemetryClient` object looks as follows - the instrumentation key is not getting populated in the `TelemetryConfiguration` for some reason and the `DisableTelemetry` is showing as true.

[image]

Any idea why the `Instrumentation Key = ""` and `DisableTelemetry = true` when running the application as an App Service in Azure?

I am guessing, since the instrumentation Key is not set, custom metrics are not getting logged in Azure Portal.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you? If you have any other questions, pls let me know.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your response. I see you have rearranged my code in the code snippet that you provided. I see you are creating a new instance of the Raft Service in the using statement and passing in the tc reference. Are you expecting the tc instance that you are passing is from the  DI container ? Can you explain the difference between your code and mine ? I am not seeing much difference other than you using the "new" word to create a instance of the Raft Service. My code works when running locally in VS2022 but not when deployed to Azure.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will test it in my side when I have time, could share the code about the application insight connection string ? Pls hide the sensitive information.

Comment: Connection String is "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralus-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://centralus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }. Yesterday, when I created a new instance of the telemetry client in my configureservices method of the startup file, it does send the metrics successfully.

Comment: The code is var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
                telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];
                var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
                services.AddSingleton(telemetryClient); My understanding from the documentation is though that I do not have to create a new instance of the telemetryclient and it is automatically added as a singleton class. Without the above four lines of code, the metrics does not get sent over.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like below.

```
public class RaftService: IDisposable
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _tc;
    private readonly Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();
    private readonly string _operationName;
    
    public RaftService(TelemetryClient tc, string operationName,ILogger<RaftService> logger,
                IHttpClientFactory clientFactory,
                IOptions<RaftOptions> raftOptions,
                IOrderNoteService orderNoteService)
    {
        _tc = tc;
        _operationName = operationName;
        _logger = logger;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _options = raftOptions;
        _orderNoteService = orderNoteService;
        _sw.Start();
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _sw.Stop();
        _tc.GetMetric(_operationName).TrackValue(_sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it.

```
using(new RaftService(tc, "metricName"))
{
    // 
}
```

Finally, you can check the logs.